# Hibernate fails on sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, exception, spring-transactions

I want to save entity with unique fields. Instead of checking if the constrains are not violated I want just to skip `DataIntegrityViolationException` somehow.

I've found that I can do it in the following way:

```
@Transactional
wrapperMethod() {
    methodWhenInsertIsDone();
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
methodWhenInsertIsDone() {
    failingMethod();
}

failingMethod(){
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().blablabla()
}
```

When I run it I get the following exception:

```
HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session
```

All these methods are in a service layer class. `@EnableTransactionManagement` exists, `HibernateTransactionManager` is defined. Everything works fine without `@Transactional`.

Could you please tell me whats wrong here or/and maybe suggest another way to swallow `DataIntegrityViolationException` exception without try/catch block.

Thanks for every idea in advance!

**UPDATE**: I'm moving the `methodWhenInsertIsDone` in another class as now it is called not from the proxy object.

**UPDATE**: Exception is gone but `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` doesn't help. So now I need to look for the other solution swallow `DataIntegrityViolationException`. If you have any please let me know. I could create a new question for it.

Comment: Include your configuration. Also if all those classes are in a single class your call to `methodWhenInsertIsDone` will not result in a new transaction.

Comment: @M. Deinum Thanks, I've just found it too. I will update the question. I guess I will have to move the `methodWhenInsertIsDone` method to another class.

Answer (score 0):

I've moved the methodWhenInsertIsDone in another class as it was called not from the proxy object. Exception is gone.

However `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` doesn't help. So now I need to look for the other solution to swallow `DataIntegrityViolationException`. If you have any please let me know. I could create a new question for it.